# React-Redux will not render, how do I troubleshoot what is going on?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I am in the middle of developing an application in React with Redux and it's frustrating when nothing renders and no errors appear. Can anybody provide some troubleshooting practices in such a situation?

I saw a similar post: [React/Redux Component will not render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823199/react-redux-component-will-not-render)

and I tried to implement the suggestions there, but it did nothing for me, I just continued to get a blank stare from the browser.

This is my reducers/reducer_books.js:

```
// Step 1. Developing Our Reducer.
// Step 2. In index.js we will wire it in so that it will work
// this is a reducer, just a function and a return with a piece of our application state, a list of books
// to be able to make use of this reducer function anywhere else in our application, we need to export it.
// with export default any other file in our application can import this one and it will just automatically
// receive the books reducer.
export default function() {
  return [ // return array
    {title: 'Coding with Javascript for Dummies'}, // these will be a couple of different books
    {title: 'Meaningful Work'},
    {title: 'Head First Javascript'},
    {title: 'How To Do Everything With Javascript'},
  ]
}
```

This is my reducers/index.js:

```
// Step 2. In index.js we will wire it in so that it will work
// importing Javascript objects that contain methods we need to use
// in order to use React. They are the react library.
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import BooksReducer from './reducer_books';

// we need to ensure that this code is generating usable state for our
// application by creating a booklist component within react
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // this gives us the same mapping of state
    // key is books and value is BooksReducer
    // passing this into the function combineReducers is essentially telling
    // reduce how to create our application state
    // the single piece of state is books
    books: BooksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

This is the component I promoted to a container in container/book-list.js:

```
// purpose of this component is to render a list of books
// we are going to use the react-redux library by making use of one of our components
// as a container instead.
// A container is a react component that has a direct connection to the state
// managed by redux.
// React and Redux are two separate libraries, this file is the melding of both
// libraries, thereby making this component aware of the state contained in Redux.
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// pulling off a single property called connect
// this is the glue between React and Redux, only through this library do we
// merge them. React-Redux in turn makes this connect function available.
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class BookList extends Component {
  // new function
  renderList() {
    // plugin our application state as this.props.books
    return this.props.books.map((book) => { // mapping the array
        return (
          // for each book in the array, we create a list with title
          <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li> // because it is a list we have to add a key
        );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
        // when calling a separate function inside of JSX, we write curly braces
        // this calls a new function of renderList
        // helper function, which is a function that helps another function
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
// This function is the glue between React and Redux.
// purpose of this function is to take our application state as an argument
// our state contains the array of books and the active book
// The argument is a state that returns an object.
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // Whatever is returned will show up as props
  // inside of BookList
  return {
    // the object returned with a key of books and a value of state.books
    // because our books reducer is returning the books property, the array of
    // objects.
    books: state.books
  };
}

// the connect function says take this component, take this map.state to props
// and returns a container. The container is aware of the state in Redux.
// In a container file we do not want to export the BookList, we want to export
// the container
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

This is the book-list/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is the components/app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

import BookList from '../containers/book-list';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BookList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Adding webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Chrome debug tools for React and Redux?  Are you using the dev version of React?  That will give you good error messages.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, I have installed the React feature for Chrome Dev Tools, but it usually pops up once it recognizes the app as a React app. In this case, it does not appear to recognize it as a React application.

Comment: Did this work before you added Redux?  I don't see ReactDOM in here.

Comment: @jmargolisvt, yeah before I started developing it had a boilerplate "react simple starter" was what it rendered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw a debugger in your code. Then open Chrome Dev Tools panel. Navigate to the console tab.

The debugger looks like this (you can put it anywhere not in a return statement):

```
class BookList extends Component {
  // new function
  renderList() {

    debugger

    // plugin our application state as this.props.books
    return this.props.books.map((book) => { // mapping the array
        return (
          // for each book in the array, we create a list with title
          <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li> // because it is a list we have to add a key
        );
    });
  }
  //...
```

If your code runs past your debugger it will stop in the console and allow you to interact with your current scope.

So you'd be able to type `this.props.books` in the console and see if its giving you what you'd expect.

It is also handy for checking which code is running.

Does anything load when you access the page? When you inspect the html see if your index.html content is loaded. It'd be invisible on the page, as it has no actual content, but can be viewed in the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: hey experiments, I placed the debugger in there and typed this.props.books in the console and I get this in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'books' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:11. To answer your question in Elements the stylesheets, the javascript and the container class is loading.

Comment: That is valuable info. That means where you put your debugger this.props = undefined. You can trace that up by moving the debugger to functions which lead to that functions call to see where you lose your props. (or just adding a ton of debuggers and watching the flow of your app.)

You also seem to be missing `MapPropsToState'. That may be important in getting that info into the right place. 

Are you running webpack by chance?

Comment: Experiments, I did add mapStateToProps, and I also added my webpack.config.js file above.

Comment: sorry my bad. Been a long day. I meant `MapDispatchToProps`. I dont really see anything above aligning with `dispatch` or `action` so the route your code takes to render is a little fuzzy to me without being able to see the whole picture. Definitely play with that debugger statement to see how things are flowing. 

Also how are you inserting content into your page in your entry file?

Comment: Experiment, isn't dispatch and action part of the Flux architecture? This is using Redux. That last question is a good one, because I just saw that my src/index.js file is completely empty.

Comment: hmm maybe it is. I always thought it was part of react-redux as that's all I import to use it. Anywho, glad you found a starting point for your fix.

Comment: Hey Experiment, that empty src/index.js was the problem. I added the imports the middleware constant and the ReactDOM.render and voila! thanks for your help and patience.